# In SSIS Lookup transformation, what happens if I add "top 100" to the select

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a very slow lookup transformation in my data flow. It uses a result of the following SQL Query

```
SELECT e.intExpenseID, [expense_detail_id]=d.intExpenseDtlID, f.*
FROM dbo.tblExpense e
JOIN tblExpenseDtl d ON d.intExpenseID = e.intExpenseID
JOIN tblExpReceiptFile f ON f.intExpenseDtlID = d.intExpenseDtlID
ORDER BY e.intExpenseID
```

The problem is, this lookup alone increases the execution time from ~1min to ~12min, which is strange, as for each row there should be no more then 4-5 files. So I added `top 1000` to the `SELECT`, my question is- will this give me the result of ( my row join from the lookup transformation ) TOP # , or will it give me a result of my row join (lookup transformation top #). If the second one, I would be grateful for any hints how I can make the lookup faster.

Just in case someone is wondering, there is a reason why I perform a lookup, instead of getting all the data at the beginning.

Comment: You can either pre-cache all of the lookup data, or parameterise cache fail SQL statement : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/implement-a-lookup-in-no-cache-or-partial-cache-mode

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that the lookup transformation works in the `my row join (lookup transformation top #)`, which means it was a bad solution to my problem.

The solution that actually worked, was to create additional OLE DB Source, and then in place of the lookup transformation, merge join it with my previous data flow

Comment: If the two datasets are on the same server then just use SQL.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid If you are asking why I'm not just extracting all the data transformation in my original source- I have to use the data before the join happens with other ssis components.